# Ejecutar scripts con loops infinitos en flask

Tags: python, flask

Me compre un raspberry pi, sensores y relays para automatizar un invernadero. Todavía no me llegó pero ya estoy haciendo pruebas simulando datos. Hasta ahí, no hay problema.

La idea es poder controlar las luces,el riego y el sistema de ventilación.
Para esto, estoy usando Python y Flask. 
Controlar todo de manera manual(a través del servidor web), no fue problema en cuanto al código.

El problema que tengo es que no sé como hacer para ejecutar un script que incluya un loop infinito desde "la web"(localhost) y que te permita volver a el "index" mientras se ejecuta.

Me explayo un poco mas, la idea es setear "que se prenda la luz si la temperatura baja de 20 grados"(va a haber varios setups así -no funcionando de manera simultanea- dependiendo en cual etapa de crecimiento están las plantas) que eso funcione de manera infinita y que mientas en mi "index" yo pueda ver los datos de temperatura, si la luz está prendida y algunos gráficos.

En cuanto a la lógica del "automático" no tengo problema.

Pongo un ejemplo. Obviamente, ese loop es infinito y no sale nunca del while y por lo tanto, al `return redirect(url_for('Index'))` que es lo que quiero.
Me dicen que tengo que aprender para poder hacer algo así?

```
@app.route('/leer-dht-data')
def ultima_entrada():
    while True:
        print("acá debe ir la lógica que controla los sensores y los relay")
        time.sleep(5) #para que se fije cada 5 segundos si hubo cambios
    return redirect(url_for('Index'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este tipo de bucles infinitos no puedes hacerlos dentro de un manejador de ruta de Flask, porque bloqueas al hilo que está atendiendo a ese cliente, que no podrá entonces atender a más cliente, y porque el protocolo HTTP "normal" no está preparado para que el servidor vaya enviando actualizaciones periódicas (aunque sí hay "extensiones" de HTTP para permitirlo, que comentaré luego).

Debe separar el problema en dos:

- Hacer un bucle de control para los sensores y relays, que deba ejecutarse en bucle inifito, pero *fuera* del servidor Flask.
- Hacer el mecanismo por el cual el cliente pueda recibir el nuevo estado de las variables.

Y comunicar entre sí de alguna forma ambas partes.

Para el primer problema, una solución típica suele ser usar otro programa python para el bucle de control, que se comunica con el programa Flask mediante algún sistema de mensajería, o mediante redis. Python tiene un módulo llamado [`celery`](http://www.celeryproject.org/) para este tipo de cosas, y Flask lo [integra fácilmente](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/celery/) y hasta tiene una extensión [`flask-celery`](https://github.com/ask/Flask-Celery).

El segundo problema es más complejo. La solución más simple es implementar lo que se llama *polling*, mecanismo en el que es el cliente quien, cada cierto tiempo (puede ser por ejemplo cada segundo), hace una petición HTTP GET a una ruta del servidor para obtener los nuevos valores. Esta petición se implementará en JavaScript usando AJAX, por ejemplo, y una vez recibida la respuesta se actualizaría la parte de la vista que deba ser modificada según el dato recibido.

La solución mejor sería hacer uso de WebSockets, que son un protocolo que permite al navegador (también desde javascript) crear un canal bidireccional con el servidor, de alguna forma independiente de HTTP (aunque en realidad va sobre él). En este canal tanto cliente como servidor pueden enviar información en cualquier momento. Esta solución es bastante compleja porque requiere programación asíncrona en el lado cliente (javascript), mediante el registro de *callbacks* que serian invocados cada vez que el servidor envíe un dato. En el lado servidor necesitarías algún módulo para Flask que implemente el protocolo Websocket. Uno bastante famoso es [flask-SocketIO](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). El problema es que debido a esa conexión "permanente" entre cliente y servidor, se necesita un hilo separado para atender a cada cliente, o bien programación asíncrona en el lado servidor.

El servidor de desarrollo de Flask no soporta esto, y deberías usar Flask "detrás" de otro servidor que sí lo soporte, como Gunicorn con el módulo eventlet. Es un tema bastante complicado, al menos con Flask. Es algo más sencillo en frameworks asíncronos que se basen en `asyncio`, pero estos son muy nuevos aún.

Otra posibilidad es utilizar el protocolo SSE (Server Sent Events), similar a WebSocket en el sentido de que el servidor puede enviar actualizaciones en cualquier momento por una conexión permanente, pero en este caso la comunicación es unidireccional (sólo del servidor al cliente), que para tu caso podría servir (para recibir las actualizaciones de los sensores, para enviar comandos podrías seguir usando un GET o POST HTTP normal). Su ventaja es que es más sencillo de integrar con Flask, gracias al módulo [`flask-sse`](https://github.com/singingwolfboy/flask-sse). El principal inconveniente es que SSE no está soportado por algunos navegadores, aunque sí por la mayoría.

En todo caso, tanto websockets como SSE son más complejos que el simple *polling*, por el que te recomendaría comenzar.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, como siempre. Muchas gracias. Voy a investigar sobre celery y polling, seguro volveré con más preguntas.